# Translate JSON in Django

Tags: python, json, django, translation

I have a Django App which uses many JSON files to render content on HTML pages via Django templates.

Now it comes to translate the whole app and the content that I have in the JSONs need to be translated as well. I tried to figure out a way to do this but I can't. The JSON is being read by a python script that reads all of them and saves their content inside a dictionary. So basically it should all be reduced to translate python code via ugettext.

But that is just my approach to the problem and it doesn't work. How would you do this? I'd like to know a general approach to tackle this problem.

Thanks to anyone who will answer.

Comment: What do you mean by 'translate' the app? Can you post some code as to what you have tried? Right now I'm confused on what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I didn't post code on purpose because I need more a general approach and I wouldn't even know what code to post since there is not a specific thing not working. Is the general process that is unclear to me.

Translating: I mean use Django u18n functions to generate .po files and use them to translate the app.

Comment: Well, when you create your dictionary just put translated values into it and then serialize. It's pretty much the same as transalations inside HTML except you don't have special tools for that (because you don't need them because of JSON's simplicity). There's no hidden truth behind this.